# Issue with the blank non mandatory date field in JAXB in SOAP UI

Tags: java, xml, date, soap, jaxb

I am working on financial sector project in jaxb technology. Have developed a web service consumption part and got stuck into a issue BEEN REPORTED FROM CLIENT END. I have two fields in my bean class of date type as follows

```
 @XmlElement(name = "abc")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    private Date abc;

    @XmlElement(name = "qwe")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    private Date qwe;
```

Now when these fields does not have data then it gives exception 
Also these fields are not mandatory, takes date in yyyy-mm-dd as per the gregorian calender as per the annotation tags. 
The reqest when done testing at local end using SOAP UI

```
            </data>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <abc></qwe>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <qwe></qwe>
            </data>


Exception Description: The object [], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[abc-->abc/text()]] with descriptor [XMLDescriptor(fully qualified package name --> [])], could not be converted to [class java.util.Calendar].
```

Same is the case for both of these fields and works well when the date is filled only in the expected format.

I donot know how to handle this issue properly either through tags or any other means as it gives exception at the bean class itself does not even reaches the service layer.

Any suggestion to solve the problem is appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Base Problem

Empty `String` is not a valid value for the `xsd:date` type.  To be valid with the XML schema an optional element should be represented as an absent node.,

---

### Why the Base Problem is Impacting You

All JAXB implementations will recognize that empty `String` is not a valid value for `xsd:date`.  They do this by reporting it to an instance of `ValidationEventHandler`.  You can see this yourself by doing the following:

```
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The implementation of JAX-WS you are using, leverages [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as the JAXB provider.  And in the version you are using MOXy will by default throw an exception when a `ValidationEvent` of severity `ERROR` is encountered instead of `FATAL_ERROR` like the reference implementation.  This has since been fixed in the following bug:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/369994

---

### Work Around

If you are using the JAXB APIs directly you could simply override the default `ValidationEventHandler`.  In a JAX-WS environment a `XmlAdapter` can be used to provide custom conversion logic.  We will leverage an `XmlAdapter` to override how the conversion to/from `Date` is handled.

**XmlAdapter (DateAdapter)**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date>{

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        if(v.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return dateFormat.parse(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        if(null == v) {
            return null;
        }
        return dateFormat.format(v);
    }

}
```

**Java Model (Root)**

The `XmlAdapter` is referenced using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.  If you wish this `XmlAdapter` to apply to all instances of `Date` you can register it at the package level (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html).

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=DateAdapter.class, type=Date.class)
    private Date abc;

    @XmlSchemaType(name="date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=DateAdapter.class, type=Date.class)
    private Date qwe;

}
```

---

### Demo Code

Below is a standalone example you can run to see that everything works.

**jaxb.properties**

In a standalone example to use MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.propeties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <abc></abc>
    <qwe>2013-09-05</qwe>
</root>
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum18617998/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Note that in the marshalled XML the `Date` field that was null was marshalled as an absent element (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <qwe>2013-09-05</qwe>
</root>
```